# How to Bind textbox/ListBox from one List with depending on other Dropdownlist populated with Another Sharepoint list in InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I have a `DropDownList` which is populated with One SharePointList in `INFOPATH DESIGNER` and the value for other textboxes are filled depending on this DropDownList Selected Value using Rules & Action. This works fine.

But, now i want to retrieve data in TextBox or ListBox which is present in Other List.`(Want to use ClientID as LookUp value)`depending on the Selected value of Dropdownlist.

```
Eg: ClientList(ClientID,Name,City)
    ClientAddress(ClientID,Address1,Address2)

Depending on ClientID from DropDownList the TextBox Value must be filled with Corresponding Address1,Address2.
```

Help Appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: [Answered it](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/60198/8319) in another dupe

Comment: @GennadyVanin--Novosibirsk thanks for replying! but i want to it with two different SharePoint Lists as mentioned above. Plz guide me to do!

Answer (score 1):

Create a data connection to the other list, then create rules to fill the text field. There are several ways:

1. Set the ID field of the query fields in the new data connection to the value of the form field, then query the data connection, set the value of the target field to the data field of the new data connection
2. set the value of the target field to the value of the new data connection, filtered by the ID value of the form field.